# Problem binding a subclass to parent class in SwiftUI View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've been experimenting on trying to binding subclass to a SwiftUI view that takes it parent class as a parameter.

These are my classes:

```
class Animal {
    func sound() -> String {
        return ""
    }
}

class Cat : Animal {
    override func sound() -> String {
        return "Meow"
    }
    
    func purr() {
        print("purring")
    }
}

class Dog : Animal {
    override func sound() -> String {
        return "Woof"
    }
    
    func fetch() {
        print("fetching")
    }
}
```

Here are the views I have set up.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var creature:Cat = Cat()
    
    var body: some View {
        AnimalView(creature: $creature)
    }
}

struct AnimalView: View {
    @Binding var creature:Animal
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(creature.sound())
            .padding()
    }
}
```

This results in the compile error:

`Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Cat>' to expected argument type 'Binding<Animal>'`

What the proper way to do bind to a view the takes a parent class?

Comment: Using `@State` and `@Binding` with a `class` rather than a `struct` doesn't make sense, because classes are passed by reference already. Are you *sure* you want classes? Also, are you sure that you want to use class inheritance for this? It looks like it might be a better fit for protocol conformance.

Comment: Yes you a right that it probably doesn't have to be classes and protocol conformance could be used. However that would have the same problem as it appears that since generics are not covariant in swift so Binding<Cat> could not be passed to Binding<Animal> even if Cat conformed to the Animal protocol. I am coming from a background of using C# where you can do things like that.

Comment: The solution you arrived at (generic views) is exactly what I was going to suggest if you could use protocols -- sounds like you got to the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

Searching around I think the structure I would want is to make the view itself generic.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var creature:Cat = Cat()
    @State var creature2:Dog = Dog()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        AnimalView(creature: $creature)
        AnimalView(creature: $creature2)
        }
    }
}

struct AnimalView<T:Animal> : View {
    @Binding var creature:T
    @State var sound:String = "No Sound"

    var body: some View {
        Text(creature.name)
            .padding()
            .onAppear {
                self.sound = self.creature.sound()
            }
    }
}
```

This will allow me to bind to types that inherit from Animal and let me use one view rather that having to create a separate Cat and Dog view.

Also just in case for better form, here is a same thing with protocol and classes.

```
protocol Animal {
    var name:String {
        get
    }
    
    func sound() -> String
}

struct Cat : Animal {
    var name:String {
        get {
            return "Cat"
        }
    }
    
    func sound() -> String {
        return "Meow"
    }
    
    func purr() {
        print("purring")
    }
}

struct Dog : Animal {
    var name:String {
        get {
            return "Dog"
        }
    }
    
    func sound() -> String {
        return "Woof"
    }
    
    func fetch() {
        print("fetching")
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any way to store the Dog and cat in the same Animal Array and render it using ForEach?

Comment: You should still be able to do a foreach and treat them all as Animal references. You can also bind a var of type [T] in AnimalView and since T is restricted to an Animal it will still use them as animals. If you want to use them as Cats or Dogs you would need to test them and cast them to the sub class to be able to access and Cat or Dog sub property. Since sound() comes from the Animal protocol you can use it with out casting since it know both Cats and Dogs have that method.